Having a problem creating a micro frontend app with npx "npx create-mf-app"
executing command npx create-mf-app results in:
Not sure why it's looking in my "roaming" folder as opposed to "local"
39 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Roaming\npm'
40 verbose cwd E:\ideaprojects
41 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
42 verbose node v20.12.2
43 verbose npm  v10.5.0
44 error code ENOENT
45 error syscall lstat
46 error path C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Roaming\npm
47 error errno -4058
48 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Roaming\npm'
49 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
49 error enoent
50 verbose exit -4058
51 timing npm Completed in 395ms
52 verbose code -4058
53 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-04T19_38_18_671Z-debug-0.log

